# Identificador de palabra

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Estoy realizando un proyecto en netbeans algún código que me puedan proporcionar ya que necesito identificar una palabra dentro de un texto y al momento de escribirla envié una alerta a un usuario esto lo estoy trabajando en java y con un repositorio alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: `String.contains()`

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Almacene la cadena de texto en una variable tipo String para que pueda utilizar el método contains de dicha clase para comparar la existencia de una palabra o letra.

```
    String cadena =  "Esto es una cadena ";

    if(cadena.contains("una")){
        //Código para cuando se cumple la condición
    }
```